# How to get the height of widgets in ListView in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, performance, dart

I am creating a widget that takes a `List` of `Widget`s and allows selecting a `Widget` upon them, that's when this `Widget` will become decorated (for example a colored rectangle will be drawn around it). I used `CustomMultiChildLayout` widget because I need the height of the `Widget`s in the `List` in order to animate the decorated rectangle from a `Widget` to another `Widget` (i.e. I am drawing the animated rectangle above the other widgets and translating and resizing it).

The problem is that when I use `CustomMultiChildLayout` with large widget lists, I am losing the performance that native flutter `ListView` provides as lazy rendering, because the `CustomMultiChildLayout` renders all the widgets, even the non-visible ones. And if I want to implement this again in my widget, I feel like re-creating the wheel. So The question is: Is there a way to get the height and width of the items in the `ListView` so that I can use a `ListView` instead of using a `CustomMultiChildLayout` ?

note: The widgets in the `List` may have different heights and widths, so an additional constraint that complicates the problem more.

Just as a minimal example of how my code looks like:

```
CustomMultiChildLayout(
              delegate: SelectableListViewLayoutDelegate(
                itemCount: widget.children.length,
              //...
              ),
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < widget.children.length; i++)
                  LayoutId(
                    id: i,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: widget.children[i],
                      onTap: () {
                     //...
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                if (widget.controller?.selectedIndex != null)
                  LayoutId(
                    id: -1,
                    child: selectedItemOverlayWidget, // this is the decorated rectang
                  ),
              ],
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping LayoutBuilder for child-widget in ListView? Then get the maxHeight of widget through constraints.

Comment: If you know how `MultiChildLayout` works the you will know that the sizes and positions of the widgets are all provided to you at the same time (in `performLayout`, this can not be performed when using `Layoutbuilder`, so your solution does not work at all here as I need the sizes of all rendered widgets in the list in order to know where to place the decorated rectangle.

Comment: I got it. Or you can just set some types for your list-item size. Model brings the type of list-item and according to type to decide to use decorated rectangle or not. For ListView if you have multiple and unexpected sizes of list-item, it will be heavy work for Flutter.